# How many prime number mysteries are tied up in the Riemann hypothesis?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose the most general form of the Riemann hypothesis were established, say, the [Generalized Riemann Hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Riemann_hypothesis) (GRH), or even the "[Grand Riemann Hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Riemann_hypothesis)."
How many of the various unsolved problems concerning prime numbers would be thereby
resolved?

I know that the GRH is now known to imply that every odd number $\ge 7$ is the sum
of three primes.  And other conjectures would be settled with the GRH.
But my sense is that [many unknowns about prime numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aConjectures_about_prime_numbers) would remain standing
even after GRH is proved.  I ask because at one time I naively assumed that the Riemann hypothesis was the key to the primes, but now I am not so sure.  Would it at least
greatly clarify the distribution of the primes?

I am aware this is not a precise question, but perhaps those knowledgeable could educate us.

Comment: Consequences of GRH spelled out in some detail at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17209/consequences-of-the-riemann-hypothesis --- any questions beyond what's there? See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_hypothesis#Consequences_of_the_generalized_Riemann_hypothesis

Comment: Thanks, Gerry, I missed that MO question and the amazing answer by Keith Conrad!

Comment: Maybe you should ask what about primes is _not_ proved by GRH?

Comment: @T97778, plenty --- Goldbach, twin primes, primes of form $n^2+1$, prime between $n$ and $n+2(\log n)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

It says nothing about large prime gaps, because these can occur in clumps followed by many primes close together, and have no real effect on any averages. Note that the standard conjectures are sort of like this: if $p$ is a prime and $q$ the very next prime, then
$$ ? ? \; \;   q < p + 3 \log^2 p \; \; ? ? $$
Note that this is true for $p=2,$ and all known $p,$ because of the extra 3 coefficient I put in.

P S. See the latest edition of Unsolved Problems in Number Theory by Richard K. Guy. I met him in San Diego. Not much to talk about, really.

Comment: May we all still be attending JMM when we are 96! :-)